PostgreSQL query for currency conversion rates
Let's consider the database table for currency conversion looks as below:



fromCurrency
toCurrency
effective date
conversion rate




USD
INR
1-Mar-2024
80


USD
INR
1-Jan-2024
85


USD
GBP
1-Oct-2023
.80


USD
GBP
1-Mar-2024
.85


USD
AUD
1-Mar-2023
1.55


USD
AUD
1-Mar-2024
1.60



If database is queried on 1-Feb-2024, to get the conversion rate where fromCurrency='USD', it should return



fromCurrency
toCurrency
effective date
conversion rate




USD
INR
1-Jan-2024
85


USD
GBP
1-Oct-2023
.80


USD
AUD
1-Mar-2023
1.55



The same query on 15-April-2024 should return



fromCurrency
toCurrency
effective date
conversion rate




USD
INR
1-Mar-2024
80


USD
GBP
1-Mar-2024
.85


USD
AUD
1-Mar-2024
1.60



Basically for all possible combinations of (fromCurrency, toCurrency) there many many records in the database and on a particular date when the database is queried only one of those many records is applicable based on the effective date. I am trying to figure out the best possible postgres query to get the records.

Please share the query you have so far.

"best possible postgres query" best in what regard? What is the criteria to compare possible solutions?

@aled sorry my bad, I meant in terms of performance. The table has a very large volume of data.

Both in jOOQ and native PostgreSQL, you can use DISTINCT ON, which is a clause where you can request only the first record per DISTINCT ON expression, given the ORDER BY clause:
With SQL:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fromCurrency, toCurrency) 
  fromCurrency, toCurrency, effectiveDate, conversionRate
FROM conversions
WHERE effectiveDate <= :currentDate
ORDER BY fromCurrency, toCurrency, effectiveDate DESC

With jOOQ (since you tagged the question with jOOQ):
var c = CONVERSIONS.as("c");

ctx.select(c.FROM_CURRENCY, c.TO_CURRENCY, c.EFFECTIVE_DATE, c.CONVERSION_RATE)
   .distinctOn(c.FROM_CURRENCY, c.TO_CURRENCY)
   .from(c);
   .where(c.EFFECTIVE_DATE.le(currentDate))
   .orderBy(c.FROM_CURRENCY, c.TO_CURRENCY, c.EFFECTIVE_DATE.desc())
   .fetch();

See this db-fiddle

Here is a query that can get you the conversion rate on a specific system date. If you don't want to use the system date, you are going to need to replace current_date, with a parameter.
WITH currList AS (
   SELECT *,
          max(effectiveDate) FILTER(WHERE effectiveDate <= CURRENT_DATE) OVER(PARTITION by fromCurrency, toCurrency) as maxEffDate
   FROM ConversionRates
)
SELECT *
FROM currList 
WHERE effectiveDate = maxEffDate


Try the following PostgreSQL query to get the applicable conversion rates based on the query date (or pickup system date):
SELECT
  from_currency,
  to_currency,
  MAX(effective_date) FILTER (WHERE effective_date <= '2023-12-05') AS effective_date,
  MAX(conversion_rate) FILTER (WHERE effective_date <= '2023-12-05') AS conversion_rate
FROM conversion_rates
WHERE from_currency = 'USD'
GROUP BY from_currency, to_currency
ORDER BY from_currency, to_currency;

I have kept effective_date and from_currency configurable, which you might want to change (ie. pickup system date) as needed.
My Fiddle for this to play around.

This risks producing values from different rows for effective_date and conversion_rate, and thus wrong results.

If you wanted to take this approach, you could use (ARRAY_AGG(ROW(effective_date, conversion_rate) ORDER BY effective_date DESC) FILTER (WHERE effective_date <= '2024-02-01'))[1] as can be seen in this updated fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/KmjLcXLS. Unfortunately, there's no MAX(ROW(...)) support in PostgreSQL.
